# WPF: Setting a binding for all TreeViewItem instance

Tags: wpf, mvvm, styles, treeviewitem, itemcontainerstyle

Greetings,

I'm using WPF with a Model-View-ViewModel pattern, and I have a view model with an `IsSelected` property which I want to bind to a `TreeViewItem`'s `IsSelected` property for all `TreeViewItem`s in the scope. I'm attempting to do this with a `Style` and a `Setter`. This works apparently for the root-level `TreeViewItem`s, but not for their children. Why is this? How can I have this apply to all `TreeViewItem` controls?

Here is the view XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.AllAreasView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:MyApp="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="700">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Style>

    <MyApp:CountVisibilityConverter x:Key="CountVisibilityConverter" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="AreaTemplate"
                              DataType="AreaViewModel"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubareasCollectionView}">
        <WrapPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="0 0 8 0" />
            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Path=Subareas}" 
                       Text="{Binding Path=Count, StringFormat= (\{0\})}"
                       Visibility="{Binding Path=Count, Converter={StaticResource CountVisibilityConverter}}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelAreas}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AreaTemplate}">
</TreeView>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we'll need more info to answer your question. Specifically, what your view model(s) look like. Below is an example you can copy and paste that works fine.

**Window1.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Background}"/>
        </Style>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate" DataType="local:DataItem" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var dis = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
            var di = new DataItem() { Name = "Top", Background = Brushes.Red };
            di.Children.Add(new DataItem() { Name = "Second", Background = Brushes.Blue });

            dis.Add(di);
            DataContext = dis;
        }
    }

    public class DataItem
    {
        public DataItem()
        {
            Children = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public ICollection<DataItem> Children
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Brush Background
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example (and inferring the simple view model). It turns out that I had been generating two separate sets of view models and the PropertyChanged event wasn't being handled correctly on my view models since I had hooked one, and WPF the other. Following the trail of the event and examining the results of GetInvocationList() of the PropertyChanged delegate lead me to find this. Since you proved it works, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

working with view models you will get very friendly with the ItemContainerStyle property. what you were doing in your code set the data template for the root level. what you want to do is style each of the items in the treeview, which you can do like so.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelAreas}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AreaTemplate}">
</TreeView>
```

enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You have to use as mentioned below. Make use of BasedOn option

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelAreas}">
   <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleKey}"/>
   </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting this, but as noted on the accepted answer, my problem was an incorrect DataContext: I was not getting property change notifications from the view model since I was not setting it correctly on the view. This pattern works without needing to set `BasedOn` in the style, and in fact, since `StyleKey` doesn't exist in the resource dictionary, this would break it.